# Can someone translate this "요즘 모하고지내요!" please

Tags: translation

Can someone translate this in english "요즘 모하고지내요!"

Comment: Can you post your attempt at this, or anything you have tried?

Comment: “Hey, what’s up, whatcha doing?”

Answer (score 1):

correct korean sentence is '요즘 뭐하고 지내요'

difference is '뭐' to '모', Changed the sentence to make it look cute (or baby talk).

Answer (score 0):

How about this: What do you spend time doing these days?